# bootstrap table filter-control - how to unset unnecessary values from select options

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

Using Boostrap table by whenzhixin with filter-control extension.
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-filter-control

When we have many select filters, it would be great to update filter options and hide values which are not exists in current data view.

I will better explain it on `jsfiddle`.
https://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/3345/

If we choose "First" : "A" than on filter "Second" option "3" shoud be disabled / deactivated .
Generally it would be great to update all filter options after each filtering action.

I have also create an issue on https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1540

Comment: I provided an example of cascading select2 boxes I am using for exactly this purpose on another link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502307/bootstrap-table-filter-control-extension-doesnt-work-in-bootstrap-table/32525653#32525653

Comment: Are you asking how to do this, or are you making a suggestion?