# Manually provide values to Boostrap Table filter-control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I want to add `filter-control` to columns in my `Bootstrap Table` and I want to provide custom values to it manually rather than it pulling the values from the values under the column. I referred to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502307/bootstrap-table-filter-control-extension-doesnt-work-in-bootstrap-table), and I used `data-filter-data` to provide the manual values. I am seeing the `filter-control` on the UI, but I do not see the custom values that I have added.

I also have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dashamlav/uzxj95t3/13/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the id containing uppercase letters. Replacing `bsTableActiveUsers` with `bs-table-active-users` worked for me.

Additionally you need to replace `"divisionX":` in the `var divisionValues` with `"Division X" :`.